# Here implemented react-bootstrap-range-slider in react js when i use this in multiple time its problem in state handling any idea?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, rangeslider

HERE IS CODE SANDBOX LINK [CLick Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-sun-ykm5v?file=/src/App.js)

Here is the range slider link [Click Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-range-slider) which i used in react component

i have a multiple data like this

```
    {
        "srno" : "1",
        "name" : "title",
        "description" : "desc",
        "slider" : "0"
    },
    {
        "srno" : "2",
        "name" : "title",
        "description" : "desc",
        "slider" : "1"
    },
```

Here is my component map handle code

```
var returnSize = data.length > 0
    && data.map((item, i) => {
        return (
            <>
                <div className="col-md-8 mgt-10">
                        <div className="leftblocks">
                            <span className="sr-no">{ item.srno }</span>
                            <h3>{item.name}</h3>
                            <p>{item.description}</p>
                            <RangeSlider
                                value={item.slider}
                                max={1}
                                onChange={changeEvent => getRangeSliderValue(changeEvent.target.value,item.srno)}
                                // onChange={changeEvent => setValue(changeEvent.target.value)}
                            />
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-4 rightblocks mgt-10"> </div>
            </>
            );
}, this);
```

When i change slider then i want to update state i do but its not working

```
const getRangeSliderValue = (value,srno) => {
    var newData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].srno === srno) {
            data[i].value = value;
        }
        newData.push(data[i]);
    }

    setData(newData);
    // setData({...data,srno : value});
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to test the problem and provide a solution if you include a demo in your question. You could create a codesandbox demo and share the link.

Comment: @Yousaf sure wait

Comment: @Yousaf check link i updated my question 
https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-sun-ykm5v?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Problem is in the `getRangeSliderValue` function. In the `if` block, you are doing `data[i].value = value;` but the objects in `data` array do not have any property named `value`. You probably meant to do `data[i].slider = value;`. Not related to your problem but also add a `step` prop on `RangeSlider` component since the max value for the slider component in your case is 1. [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-hellman-09m6b?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)